# How to play against an engine using scid for a particular level?

Tags: engines

The best free chess program SCID vs Pc is installed and the latest chess engines are installed. After watching video Jeremy Silman, to play for first low level then intermediate and then Master level.

How to configure the SCID vs. PC to select a Particular chess engine , to play Low level or intermediate or then Master level ?

Answer (score 2):

Manage your engines in **Tools**.

[image]

Select your engine in **Play**.

[image]

Configure the engine, then select your skill level.

[image]